# eigen3: placement new syntax for Map to a const value

Tags: new-operator, eigen3

Hello all: I'm a bit confused with Eigen3 and new placement syntax because this code work:

```
double ptr1[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
const double ptr2[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
Map<Matrix<double,3,3> >    mUseless(ptr1);
new (&mUseless) Map<const Matrix<double,3,3> > (ptr2);
mUseless(1,1)=6.0;
```

If mUseless now point to a const double, why this code works??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling placement new does not change the type of the object, and since `mUseless` is not a `Map<const ...>`, it is perfectly normal that you can change the content of the referenced values.

Actually, your code is similar to a `reinterpret_cast` from a `Map<const Matrix<double,3,3> >` to a `Map<Matrix<double,3,3> >`.